# vector3(...) argument 1 had type nil

Tags: lua, fivem

I'm trying to run this 'script' in a game (FiveM), using modified framework (ESX(legacy)) and I get this error when try to do the function :(
The code at the exact lines:

```lua
function deleteLastObject(object_end, x, y, z)
    ESX.Game.DeleteObject(ESX.Game.GetClosestObject(object_end, { -----------> line 265
        x = x,
        y = y,
        z = z
    }))
end
```

```lua
function spawnEndObject(object_start, object_end, x, y, z)
    if isActionStarted then
        ESX.Game.SpawnObject(object_end, {
            x = x,
            y = y,
            z = z
        }, function(obj)
            deleteLastObject(object_start, x, y, z) -----------> line 257
            SetEntityHeading(obj, GetEntityHeading(GetPlayerPed(-1)))
            PlaceObjectOnGroundProperly(obj)
        end)
    end
end
```

I'll be glad if someone helps :)

Comment: what is object_start?   provide more information and the actual error message

Answer (score -1):

Don't use X, Y, Z in table, instead use vector3(X, Y, Z).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).